# Hue not starting after cloudera installation

Tags: cloudera-cdh, hue, cloudera-manager

After installation of Cloudera 5.16, I started Hue service but it fails to start. The error is shown in the screenshot. Any suggestions are welcome.

[image: Hue service error]

Comment: It looks like the 'hue' user does not exist on your machine?

Comment: I am doing installation using Parcels of cloudera. So, it should be present/created by  cloudera process itself.